# Install package from local Zip w/ R - 'does not exist'

Tags: libcurl, package

I recently downloaded the libcurl package in .zip format into my downloads directory.

On R I click 'Install packages from local zip file'

I find my zip file and get the following error:

> utils:::menuInstallLocal()
>   Error in read.dcf(file.path(pkgname, "DESCRIPTION"), c("Package", "Type")) : 
>     cannot open the connection
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   In read.dcf(file.path(pkgname, "DESCRIPTION"), c("Package", "Type")) :
>     cannot open compressed file 'libcurl/DESCRIPTION', **probable reason 'No such file or directory'**

Answer (score 1):

`libcurl` is not an R package. You need to install it on your machine with whatever system resources are appropriate. (The R package, `RCurl` does require that libcurl be present.)

http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/

You should probably edit the tags to include your OS and remove the zip, r and local tags, ... oh heck, I'll do the second part.